# Seam reRender component in partial; reRender across naming containers

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces

I'm using seam to develop a simple web app.
Using a4j commandButton  in many places, with the property reRender="componentName"

componentName is in most places a a4j outputPanel

Which always worked, until I used a template. with include of two different views.
reRender applied to the whole view does work, but reRender applied to an inner component does not.

Same issue with page rules, all action I had defined are not functioning any more.

Is this a problem with Seam, did someone experience this?

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="panel1">
             <h:form>
                    <div class="section">
                                      // whatever code
                                </div>

 <a4j:commandButton id="button1" value="Add" action="#{bean1.action()}" reRender="panel1"/>
 <h:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" action="#{bean1.reset}"/>
 </h:form>

</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `reRender` across naming containers you need something like `reRender=":myComponent"` - the colon in the beginning denotes absolute location of the component in the component tree. Otherwise all IDs are realized relative to the current naming container, which would be a form in this case.

See [`UIComponent.findComponent(..)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: That code is only an example. in other cases I do not want the panel to be in the form. I have pages with many forms. and some button should be refreshing some other panel(s). not the one that you recommend should be within this form.